# Query gives different result when run from site

Tags: php, mysql

I am running a search on a database, to find cruises that contain a stop a port that has been entered in a search field. So a user types 'Dublin' and they get back all the cruises that stop there.

I have two tables, cruises which contains all the cruises and itinerary which contains the stops on the cruise. they are related by cruises.id and itinerary.cruise_id

The query I have run in MySQL workbench looks like this, I put Amsterdam in as an example of what is searched for

```
SELECT id, title, code FROM cruises WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM itinerary WHERE port LIKE '%amsterdam%' AND cruises.id = cruise_id)
```

obviously in my web page, I have used

```
SELECT id, title, code FROM cruises WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM itinerary WHERE port LIKE %s AND cruises.id = cruise_id)
```

THe workbench query does exactly what I want, returns eight cruises , all stopping at Amsterdam

The web query returns eight matches, but they are all the same record ?

Any ideas ?

thanks

Rich :)

OK here's the code at the top of the page getting the search variable and doing the query

```
$colname_search = "-1";
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
 $colname_search = $_POST['search'];
}

$query_search_cruises = sprintf("SELECT id, title, code FROM cruises WHERE EXISTS     (SELECT * FROM itinerary WHERE port LIKE %s AND cruises.id = cruise_id )",     GetSQLValueString("%" . $colname_search . "%", "text"));
$search_cruises = mysql_query($query_search_cruises, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
$row_search_cruises = mysql_fetch_assoc($search_cruises);
$totalRows_search = mysql_num_rows($search_cruises);
```

And this bit is doing the output.

```
<h2><?php if($row_search_cruises["title"]) { echo "Your search for \"" . $_POST['search'] . "\"was found here.."; } else { echo "Sorry no matches have been found"; } ?></h2>
<?php do { ?>
<p><?php echo "<a href=\"cruise_details.php?id=" . $row_search_cruises["id"] . "\">{$row_search_cruises['code']}, {$row_search_cruises['title']}</a>"; ?> </p><br />
<?php } while ($row_search = mysql_fetch_assoc($search_cruises)); ?>
```

Comment: Please post the relevant PHP code.

Comment: What is the code you use to request those rows?

Comment: just added some more of the code. Perhaps it's a different loop I need ?

Comment: I'll mention this, because I see quite a few people leaving themselves open to SQL injection attacks. I don't know if GetSQLValueString sanitizes the input string, but the input search string needs sanitizing. (Google "Little Bobby Tables")

Comment: I've fixed it , can't answer my own question right now, but the problem is glaring at me now... $row_search should be $row_search_cruises , doh.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`SELECT id, title, code FROM cruises WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM itinerary WHERE port LIKE '%%s%' AND cruises.id = cruise_id)`

% is a wildcard in MySQL, it means that you can get results where amsterdam is in the middle of the text.

Not sure if this will work, perhaps you need to escape the %'s

EDIT: I assume you have echoed your query, making sure that %s actually has the content you expect?

Comment: @user1059573 and my example did not work? If it did, please accept my answer so others can use this later.

Comment: no, it wasn't that ... I've fixed the issue, answer posted below

Answer (score 0):

### Edit: Same as above-

Shouldnt the web query be?

'%amsterdam%'

NOT

'%s%'

```
    SELECT id, title, code FROM cruises WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM itinerary WHERE port LIKE %s AND cruises.id = cruise_id)
```

Comment: I assume he is making a dynamic query, using PDO or something. %s is replaced by the value of some variable.

Comment: I thought that might be the case alright. Just pointed it out incase he wasn't. Assuming causes more problems :-P

Comment: that's right it is a dynamic query, I've added more code to the question

Answer (score 0):

Just in passing, you may find replacing the "EXISTS" with a "JOIN" more efficient.

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.title, t1.code FROM cruises t1 JOIN itinerary t2 WHERE t2.port LIKE '%%s%' AND t1.id = t2.cruise_id
```

Comment: It can be down to the way MySQL optimises the query. It's not always the case but the difference can be dramatic. http://solutionfactor.net/blog/2011/11/06/mysql-inner-join-vs-exists-may-yield-better-performance/